# C# How can winform higher privileged applications receive messages from any Lower privilege modes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have windows forms application that is run as administrator, but it cannot receive any inputs from other applications that are run without administrator priviliges. How can I enforce this application to receive any inputs or messages from other lower modes applications ?

Comment: What do you mean by "receive inputs or messages"?

Comment: [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilterex)

Comment: ;If the lower privileges application is typing characters as in the following sample code
sendKeys.Send("Hello");

Comment: yes , but how can I get the full syntax of ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx() ?

Comment: @Jimi Please help me with a living example in separate answer for the function ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/CWMFEx